# Adding a label or text to an ellipse object in kivy

Tags: user-interface, kivy

I'd like to draw the x,y coordinates of a nested ellipse I have within the ellipse.  However, I'm afraid I don't understand the object hierarchy enough for how to do that.  I have tried adding a label event to be a child of the Ellipse, and I know it doesn't have a 'text' attribute that I can modify directly (as it's not a Button or a Label).  Here's what I have:

```
    MyWidget:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,0,0,1
            Ellipse:
                size: min(self.size)*0.2, min(self.size)*0.2
                pos: (self.x), (self.y)
            Label:
                text: unicode(self.x), unicode(self.y)
```

Error:

```
 >>   40:                Label:
      41:                    text: unicode(self.x), unicode(self.y)
 ...
 You can add only graphics Instruction in canvas.
```

So, I add it to a child of the Ellipse:

```
    MyWidget:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,0,0,1
            Ellipse:
                size: min(self.size)*0.2, min(self.size)*0.2
                pos: (self.x), (self.y)
                Label:
                    text: unicode(self.x), unicode(self.y)

 >>   40:                Label:
      41:                    text: unicode(self.x), unicode(self.y)
 ...
 You can add only graphics Instruction in canvas.
```

So, I try to put it in a canvas:

```
    MyWidget:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,0,0,1
            Ellipse:
                size: min(self.size)*0.2, min(self.size)*0.2
                pos: (self.x), (self.y)
                canvas:
                    Label:
                        text: unicode(self.x), unicode(self.y)
```

That doesn't have an error, but doesn't display any text.

**Updating to address excellent answer below**

```
  MyWidget:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,0,0,1
            Ellipse:
                size: min(self.size)*0.2, min(self.size)*0.2
                pos: (self.x, self.y)
        Label:
            pos: (self.x,self.y)
            size: min(self.size)*0.2, min(self.size)*0.2
            text: "{},{}".format(str(self.x),str(self.y))
```

Gives me the following error:

```
      44:            Label:
 >>   45:                pos: (self.x, self.y)
      46:                size: min(self.size)*0.2, min(self.size)*0.2
      47:                text: "{},{}".format(str(self.x),str(self.y))
 ...
 RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I still can't get the text to appear /inside/ the Ellipse.

Comment: This error comes from a mistake in my example, sorry! The problem is that the Label effectively has `pos: self.pos`, which is clearly infinitely recursive. It should instead be `pos: root.pos` (or as you wrote it, `pos: (root.x, root.y)`, to refer to the MyWidget rather than the Label itself

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you *cannot* mix the canvas with widgets.

A way to think of it is that each widget *has* a canvas. You can draw what you like on that canvas, but the keyword there is *draw* - you can use kivy graphics instructions, like Ellipse or Rectangle or Line (or contextual instructions like Translate and Rotate). However, you can't use widgets. They don't work that way, they aren't things you draw on a canvas, they are widgets. When you add one widget to another with `add_widget`, one thing that happens is that its canvas is drawn on the canvas of the other, but this is kept to the canvases - it doesn't make sense to try and draw a whole widget on a canvas.

This is the root of all of your errors; Ellipse is not a widget. It doesn't have a canvas, it's only something you draw on a canvas. It can't have children because it isn't a widget. In kv language, the keyword `canvas` (and `canvas.before` etc.) doesn't mean there's a child *widget* called canvas, it's just a special syntax referring to the canvas of the parent widget.

So, to actually fix your problem, you need to take the Label out of the canvas. Something like the following should work:

```
MyWidget:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,0,0,1
        Ellipse:
            size: min(self.size)*0.2, min(self.size)*0.2
            pos: (self.x), (self.y)
    Label:
        pos: root.pos
        size: min(self.size)*0.2, min(self.size)*0.2
        text: unicode(self.x), unicode(self.y)
```

This is of course the normal syntax for making the Label just be a child of MyWidget. The important part is it's been given the same position and size as the ellipse so, since text is centered by default, the text will appear in the middle of the ellipse. If the text is long or something you might want to play with other things like setting `text_size` to automatically wrap, but that's a different problem.

Also, once you have multiple widgets with the same size description (like the size of both the Label and Ellipse in my example), it's often neater to move that calculation to a different place - for instance a NumericProperty of MyWidget. That way you can avoid code duplication, and also make it so that if you ever change the positioning requirements you can easily update both the Label and Ellipse simultaneously.

Comment: This is interesting and enlightening in my general error, but the Label seems to be located far away from the Ellipse.  It's in the lower left of the parent widget.  If I'm defining the label outside of the Ellipse, how can I reference the position of the Ellipse itself?

Comment: Did you copy my actual code? Part of the solution is that you must set the Label's pos and size to what you want, which is what I did by defining the Label's pos and size to be the same as the Ellipse. I also commented on this in my answer, read the last paragraph.

Comment: At first, I copied your actual code and felt like I understood the distinction you were making, but my actual use-case code is doing a lot of complicated stuff positioning and repositioning the Ellipse---yours worked, but positioned the label in the corner of a parent object.  It have tried to make this all a NumericProperty of MyWidget but how to do this is apparently beyond me, and I need to practice a lot more.  I'm baffled that it's so hard to add text to a circle.  KV is a lot harder to format anything than html+css.  Thanks and all, it's just hard.

Comment: Ultimately, your Ellipse must have a `pos: some_pos` and a `size: some_size`. The only question is...what are those? You have to know that, because it's you that's setting them. If you answer that question, all you have to do is write exactly the same code for the Label's size and pos, and then it will be in precisely the right place.